# Reflection in WinRT IsAssignableFrom

Tags: reflection, winrt-xaml

I am trying to retrieve a list of types that inherit from the Page object using reflection.

I have the following object:

```
 public sealed partial class Register : Page
 { .... }
```

In another class, I am using:

```
var currentAssembly = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var page = currentAssembly.DefinedTypes.Single(t => t.Name == p.PageName);

var inherits = page.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Page).GetTypeInfo());
```

where p.PageName = Register

For some reason, inherits is false when it should be true. The definition for register and the definition for the class I have the reflection in are both in the same project also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem by using the following:

```
var pageInstance = (Page) Activator.CreateInstance(page.AsType());
if (pageInstance == null)
{
    _logger.Debug(string.Format("The type {0} does not inherit from Page and cannot be navigated to.", page.Name));
    throw new ArgumentException("Only object names deriving from Page can be navigated to.");
}
```

I would welcome a better suggestion that this though. Thanks.